# Amending text file strings and using the result to perform an xcopy

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I have a windows boot pen that runs a batch file when it starts up, all it needs to do is copy a large list of files specified in a text file from the machine to the boot pen.

I made a test run on my PC before making the boot pen and thought this should work

```
@echo off
set DRIVE=c

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (e:\test\files.txt) do call :amendDirectoryAndCopy %%a

pause

:amendDirectoryAndCopy
set DEST=%~1
set DEST=%DEST:~1%
echo set DEST=%DRIVE%%DEST%
echo xcopy %~1 %DEST%
```

all it should do is for each file, remove the first character of the string, add "c" to the beginning which gives the destination directory, then perform an xcopy. I find the output confusing as "@echo set "DEST=%DRIVE%%DEST%" outputs what I would expect, the correct directory on C: such as

c:\test\folder\file.txt

but the xcopy outputs

xcopy e:\test\folder\file.txt :\test\folder\file.txt

the drive letter is missing on the destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is needed along with its counterpart `!` replacement of `%` in variable expansion to get your code to work.

I am away from my Windows machine right now, so I cannot test the syntax, but off the top of my head, something like this should work:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
set drive=c    
set ready_to_move=0  
set file_list=e:\test\files.txt

if "!ready_to_move!" == "1" (
  set echo=
) else (
  set echo=echo
)

for /F "eol=; tokens=1 delims=" %%f in ('type "!file_list!"') do (
  set source=%%~f
  for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%s in ("!source!") do set source=%%s
  set destination=!drive!!source:~1!
  !echo! xcopy "!source!" "!destination!"
)
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Almost. I now have destination as "c                :\test\folder\file.txt

I googled around for how to remove whitespace from a variable but this doesn't seem to work for me for some reason "set detination=%destination: =%"

EDIT - Ok the formatting keeps correcting what I've written but basically theres whitespace after the letter c

Comment: Cool.  Now double check the line `set drive=c` and ensure there is no white space after the `c`.  Batch scripts are incredibly sensitive to white space anywhere.  Does that help?

Comment: in vim, i usually do one of these if I feel it is safe: `:%s/ \+$//g`
The only other possibility is that the white-space is coming from your text file.  I updated the answer to handle this.

Comment: There was whitespace after the c =) thanks a lot kikuchiyo I would never have figured out that it was whitespace.

Comment: :D  No problemo!  Good luck with your dos scripting :)

Comment: I don't suppose you could explain why my original solution didn't work could you? Your solution makes sense but I don't really understand what was wrong with mine

Comment: Sure.  Without the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and the `!` in place of `%`, the 'timing' I guess you could call it is off.  My best answer is that you need to delay the expansion of the variable, otherwise it just zips through the code so that when it sees %whatever% where whatever is set in a loop, it is empty at that point in time.  I wish I could give a more technical answer, but I just know from experience that I cannot set my variables in loops without `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `!` in place of `%`.  It's a really weird language >.<  For kicks, sub these into ur solution.